# How does SSRS wrap text parameter values when passing them to a Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services

I have a stored procedure that populates a report dataset. One of the parameters is a nullable varchar(10) defaulted to Null in the sproc def. This parameter allows users to specify an order number if they want to only report on a single order rather than all every order that satisfy the other parameterised criteria.

Order numbers are integers but they are stored in the table in a varchar(10) field prefixed with leading Zeros. (The report data is imported from an ERP system that stores it's integer Order numbers this way, hence me keeping the same *stupid* format !).

When the parameter is set to null, I get all the rows I'd expect, both when executing the Stored Procedure in SSMS and when using the "Query..." context menu option of the dataset in SSRS.

However, when I specify an Order number (wrapped in 'single quotes' so SSRS doesn't cut off the leading Zeros) in the SSRS Query Designer form, and execute the sproc, I get Zero rows returned. Yet when executing the sproc from SSMS and setting the parameter to the same value, I get the correct number of rows expected.

I have a feeling SSRS is doing something unexpected in the background when parsing the values supplied into the Stored Procedure's parameters, so my question is how should I specify a string containing an integer so I get the same results in the Query Designer as I do in SSMS? Single Quotes or something else?

*I haven't posted Code as I want to see if anyone immediately recognises this problem rather than get lots of off point, "Why are you doing this, Why don't you do that?" best practice junkie, can't think outside the box, type answers!* ;-p

However, that said, I will post code if no-one recognises this issue.

Platform: SQL Server 2008 R2, BIDS 2008.

Comment: Not seen this - so you are executing the sproc in the query designer and getting back 0 rows...can you post a screenshot of the parameters window before you run the sproc in the SSRS query designer form?

Comment: Charleh. you inadvertantly helped me solve it (I think) so thanks...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the single-quotes. I was putting them into the "Define Query Parameters" "Parameter Values" window. I was also doing this on two other parameters, one of which is being used in a "LIKE '%parametervalue%" in the WHERE clause, so the extra quotes didn't affect the query result!

So.... I'm going to do approach this differently, but the question remains, If you have a varchar field with an integer in it with leading Zeros, how do you specify a value in SSRS if you can't use single quotes?

I think this guy has the same issue
[Define query parameters visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221886/define-query-parameters-visual-studio)

Answer (score 0):

I had suspected as much, that's why I asked for the screenie :)

SSRS knows the params are string based so it doesn't require you to add the quotes.

You shouldn't need to use quotes anywhere assuming your query parameters are typed correctly (strings don't require any quotes in the front end - obviously in the query they need to be quoted or you will get an implicit cast).

If you want to deal with padding an int with leading zeroes in the back end you can do that using REPLICATE() or you can just cast the string representation of an int to an int.

e.g. to have up to 10 padded zeroes:

```
DECLARE @SomeNumericValue int
SET @SomeNumericValue = 10
SELECT RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 10) + cast(@SomeNumericValue as varchar), 10)
```

result:

```
0000000010
```

Otherwise you can get away with:

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE SomeVarcharFieldWhichActuallyContainsPaddedInts = 10
```

This is because SQL will implicitly cast the `0000000010` to int - of course this CAN throw an error if ever a non numeric value was represented in the table (and will throw for every query that attempts this cast no matter the result as SQL will cast the whole result set in order to do the comparison)

e.g. try the following script:

```
-- This will work:
DECLARE @SomeTable Table(IntString varchar(50))

insert into @SomeTable
SELECT '000001'
UNION
SELECT '000002'
UNION
SELECT '000003'

SELECT * from @SomeTable where IntString = 1

-- This WILL return some results but it won't be happy...!

insert into @SomeTable
SELECT 'Hello'

SELECT * from @SomeTable where IntString = 1
```